# Verilog implementing a<b ? 1 : 0

Tags: verilog, mips, cpu, riscv

I'm trying to understand this code and I can't wrap my head around it

```
// upper bits are always zero
assign slt[31:1] = 0;

xor (condition, a[31], b[31]);
yArith slt_arith (tmp, cout, a, b, 1);
yMux #(.SIZE(1)) slt_mux(slt[0], tmp[31], a[31], condition);
```

`a` and `b` are some 32 bit numbers

The code is trying to implement `(a < b) ? 1 : 0;` Which is known as slt in mips

the `yArith` part is doing (a-b) and places result into `tmp`, the 1 is a flag for subtraction.

the `yMux` part is 2x1 mux, that takes some condition (0 or 1) to select either `tmp[31]` if condition is 0 or `a[31]` if condition is 1.

Why does this code work to implement set on less than in Verilog?

Comment: `(a < b)` is the same as `(a < b) ? 1 : 0`, FYI.

Comment: What's the point of the xor then?

Comment: It appears that handles `a` and `b` as if they are signed 32 bit integers in 2s-complement form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` have opposing signs, then `a` can only be less than `b` if `a` is negative.

Expressed in pseudo code:

```
if (a[31] XOR b[31]) {
    result = a[31]
}
```

If `a` and `b` have the same sign, then obviously we can't just look at the sign bit of one of the operands. Instead we check if `a-b` is negative.

```
if (!(a[31] XOR b[31])) {
    result = (a-b)[31]
}
```

And if we combine these two:

```
if (a[31] XOR b[31]) {
    result = a[31]
} else {
    result = (a-b)[31]
}
```

---

If you're wondering why we're not always using `(a-b)[31]`, consider the case where `a = -2147483648` (0x80000000) and `b = 1`. Obviously -2147483648 is less than 1, but `(0x80000000-1)[31]` == `(0x7FFFFFFF)[31]`, which is 0. So that wouldn't work.